# MySQL 'count' where year range is incremental

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform 'select count' query incremental value(by 5)

Like these sql queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ages WHERE ages.year BETWEEN 1990 and 1995
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ages WHERE ages.year BETWEEN 1995 and 2000
..so fort and so on..
```

How can I make it an efficient single query?

Comment: A stored procedure, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, (ages.year DIV 5) * 5 AS bottom, 
    (ages.year DIV 5 + 1) * 5 AS top
FROM ages
GROUP BY (ages.year DIV 5) * 5, (ages.year DIV 5 + 1) * 5
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e39c8/3)

Note this assumes you in reality do *not* want to double-count those values on the boundary. It is not 100% exactly like your original query. If you indeed want to double-count, try:

```
SELECT SUM(`count`) AS `count`, bottom, top
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, (ages.year DIV 5) * 5 AS bottom, 
        (ages.year DIV 5 + 1) * 5 AS top
    FROM ages
    GROUP BY (ages.year DIV 5) * 5, (ages.year DIV 5 + 1) * 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS `count`, ages.year - 5 AS bottom, ages.year AS top
    FROM ages
    WHERE MOD(ages.year, 5) = 0
) inclusive
GROUP BY bottom, top
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e39c8/11)